# Using netsh or netstat (or other native tool) to display UDP traffic to Windows server from given host

Tags: windows, netstat, netsh

We have a Windows server that we suspect is not receiving UDP traffic from a Linux server. We've been able to establish, using tcpdump, that the Linux server is sending UDP traffic and we would like to display UDP traffic coming into the Windows server, preferably using a native Windows util such at `netsh` or `netstat`.

Comment: Any reason why you would not install Wireshark?

Comment: We ended up using Wireshark

Answer (score 0):

You can capture with the following command:

```
netsh trace start capture=yes tracefile=c:\temp\capture.etl
```

and stop with this one:

```
netsh trace stop
```

Then, you can open the ETL file with [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226), and if you want to read them in wireshark instead of Microsoft Message Analyzer, you can export the events in a .CAP file: **File** -> **Save As** -> **Export**